# Is PHP 5's autoload inefficient?

Tags: php, class, include, autoload

When you manually include a PHP class you can do it while the current script is running, right? Then you can decide, if a condition matches you load it and if it doesn't you don't. Like this:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' ) {
    include '../../../Whatever/SanitizeUserInput.class.php';
    SanitizeUserInput::sanitize($_POST['someFieldName']);
}
```

But let's say I use the [autoload](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) feature with this class. Will it be *effectively* loaded at the beginning or will it be loaded only if it's used?

I mean, should I add the `__autoload` function only in classes that I'm 100% sure I'm going to use in any script (*e.g.* database connection, session management, etc.)?

Thanks

Comment: would go with @Timur suggestion of using [spl_autoload_register](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) as it seems more flexible and from my perspective I don't see why autoload should be less efficient... the idea is to load a class only when an instance is created based on your custom logic... so you should be good with it

Comment: Using autoloading or not is also a question of clean design.

Comment: @KingCrunch - Which one do you think is the clean one?

Comment: Keep the "where is my class?" up to the autoloader and not the code, that wants to use the class. For example you use `include`, which will sooner or later result in an "class already defined".

Comment: @martinstoeckli Using autoload is better because of better portability of the class and cleaner because you don't need to write all the `include(..)` in your file.

Comment: Of course one could use `include_once()`, but i agree that in PHP using an autoloader makes the code more readable and prevents loading of unnecessary files. Was just curious about KingCrunch's opinion. Other languages may profit from declaring the usings explicitely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Autoload is called only when you are trying to access desired class. And it would be better to use [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) instead of `__autoload`

Documentation:

> You may define an __autoload() function which is automatically called
>   in case you are trying to use a class/interface which hasn't been
>   defined yet.

and

> spl_autoload_register() provides a more flexible alternative for
>   autoloading classes. For this reason, using __autoload() is
>   discouraged and may be deprecated or removed in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Autoloading kicks in when you are trying to *use* a class that has not yet been loaded:

```
include 'foo.php';
new Foo;  // autoload not used, because the class already exists

// Bar is not yet loaded here, auto or otherwise

new Bar; // Bar is being autoloaded, because it was not yet loaded
```

As such, autoloading can be *very* efficient. It's slightly less efficient than loading classes by hand at the time when you need them, because of the overhead of invoking the autoload function. But keeping track of loaded classes by hand is more work for very little return over autoload.

Answer (score 2):

Try it out, you will see, that whenever PHP stumbles over a class it doesn't know yet, it will call your autoload function. When your autoload function tells PHP in which file the class is, it will load this file.

To make the answer short, PHP only loads the file when needed, that is true even for conditions, so following test class will never be loaded.

```
if (false)
{
  $test = new CTest(); // never loaded with autoload.
}
```